# In what condition will cause LockAcquisitionException and SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, timeout, db2-luw

As my understanding, `LockAcquisitionException` will happen when a thread is trying to update a row of record that is locking by another thread. ( Please do correct me if I am wrong )

So I try to simulate as follow:

I lock a row of record using `dbVisualizer`, then I using application to run a update query on the same record as well. At the end, I am just hitting `global transaction time out` instead of `LockAcquisitionException` with reason code 68.

Thus, I am thinking that my understanding is wrong. `LockAcquisitionException` is not happen by this way. Can kindly advise or give some simple example to create the `LockAcquisitionException` ?

Comment: You can get around the locks used by older program designs by doing an optimistic update in your program.  Success or Fail (for whatever reason that may be).  Search for optimistic update.

Answer (score 1):

You will get LockAcquisitionException (SQLCODE=-911 SQLERRMC=68) as a result of a lock timeout.

It may be unhelpful to compare the actions of dbViz with hibernate because they may use different classes/methods and settings at jdbc level which can influence the exception details. What matters is that at Db2 level both experienced SQLCODE=-911 with SQLERRMC=68 regardless of the exception-name they report for the lock-timeout.

You can get a lock-timeout on statements like UPDATE or DELETE or INSERT or SELECT (and others including DDL and commands), depending on many factors.

All lock-timeouts have one thing in common: one transaction waited too long and got rolled-back because another transaction did not commit quickly enough.

Lock-timeout diagnosis and Lock-Timeout avoidance are different topics.

The length of time to wait for a lock can be set at database level, connection level, or statement level according to what design is chosen, including mixing these. You can also adjust how Db2 behaves for locking by adjusting database parameters like CUR_COMMIT, LOCK_TIMEOUT and by adjusting isolation-level at statement-level or connection-level.

It's wise to ensure accurate diagnosis before thinking about avoidance.

As you are running Db2-LUW v10.5.0.9, consider careful study of this page and all related links:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0055072.html

There are many situations that can lead to a lock timeout, so it's better to know exactly *which* situation is relevant for your case(s).

Avoiding lock-conflicts is a matter of both configuration and transaction design so that is a bigger topic. The configuration can be at Db2 level or at application layer or both.

Sometimes bugs cause lock-timeouts, for example when app-server threads have a database-connection that is hung and has not committed and is not being cleaned up correctly by the application.

You should diagnose the participants in the lock timeout. There are different ways to do lock-conflict diagnosis on Db2-LUW so choose the one that works for you.

One simple diagnosis tool that still works on V10.5.0.9 is to use the Db2-registry variable DB2_CAPTURE_LOCKTIMEOUT=ON, event though the method is deprecated. You can set this variable (and unset it) on the fly without needing any service-outage. So if you have a recreatable scenario that results in SQLCODE=-911 SQLERRMC=68 (lock timeout), you can switch on this variable, repeat the test, then switch off the variable. If the variable is switched on, and a lock timeout happens, Db2 will write a new text file containing information about the participants in the locking situation showing details that help you understand what is happening and that lets you consider ways to resolve the issue when you have enough facts.  You don't want to keep this variable permanently set because it can impact perormance and fill up the Db2 diagnostics file-system if you get a lot of lock-timeouts. So you have to be careful.  Read about this variable in the Knowledge Center at this page:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005657.html
You diagnose the lock-timeout by careful study of the contents of these files, although of course it's necessary to understand the details also. This is a regular DBA activity.

Another method is to use db2pdcfg -catch with a custom db2cos script, to decide what to do after Db2 throws the -911. This needs scripting skills and it lets you decide exactly what diagnostics to collect after the -911 and where to store those diagnostics.

Another method which involves much more work but potentially pays more dividends is to use an `event monitor for locking`. The documentation is at:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054074.html
Be sure to study the "Related concepts" and "Related tasks" pages also.

Comment: I am trying the DB2_CAPTURE_LOCKTIMEOUT, will get back to here once the result come back.