# com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlTransactionRollbackException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68, DRIVER=3.65.110

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, locking, deadlock

Know that there is a lot of question of this. This is cause by the row of data is update by other thread, and the other thread could not acquire the lock.
However, I am trying to ask in more details:

I have some code as follow:

```
// catch all for hibernate super exception
    public SystemErrorCode map(final org.hibernate.JDBCException dae) {
        log.info( "dae : " + dae );
        log.info( "dae error code : " + dae.getErrorCode( ) );
        log.info( "dae sql : " + dae.getSQL( ) );
        log.info( "dae sql exception : " + dae.getSQLException( ) );
        log.info( "dae sql state : " + dae.getSQLState( ) );
        log.info( "dae cause : " + dae.getCause( ) );
        log.info( "dae message : " + dae.getMessage( ) );
        return new SystemErrorCode( "DAO0005", SYSTEM_DAO );
    }
```

And here is the log:

```
dae : org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
dae error code : -911
dae sql : update PHistory SET  currentStatus = :currentStatus , MODIFIEDDATETIME = CURRENT TIMESTAMP where pHistoryId = :pHistoryId 
dae sql exception : com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlTransactionRollbackException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68, DRIVER=3.65.110
dae sql state : 40001
dae cause : com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlTransactionRollbackException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68, DRIVER=3.65.110
dae message : could not execute native bulk manipulation query
```

As I check on the code, actually there is no other thread to update the same record, because the pHistory is the primary and its unique.

However, I am keep hitting this thing in production, and I cant simulate it in my local or either SIT or UAT. I am trying to know what thread, or from where of my code I am actually locking the same row, and then causing this error.

Comment: You need to involve your Db2 DBA (if you have one). The "other thread" might not be your application.  There are plenty of features in the Db2-server (depending on the Db2-version, which you did not mention) to advise exactly what is the other thread and also the SQL that both threads are running.   Also you are using a very old (out of support) jdbc driver from Db2 v10.1 fixpack 4 although this is NOT the cause of the problem.  If you *dont* have a Db2 DBA, then update your question with the Db2-version+fixpack of the Db2-server.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your question asked in March 2018, you did not respond to the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106741/in-what-condition-will-cause-lockacquisitionexception-and-sqlcode-911-sqlstate

Comment: Hi @mao, thanks for your help for so long time. I am finally found the root cause and post my solution (for my case) at follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the root cause and manage to solve it. Its actually cause by the huge number of PHistory table records, and many linkage with other table, and less of indexing.

I run a `db2expln` on this query and found that add the suggested index will improve 99% of the performance. After I add the index, and monitoring for few months, and good news that is no more this exception happen in my program.

So, its actually not cause by other thread updating the same row, I am finding the solution in wrong way. Until I check the index. Thus, in future, if there is some similar issue happen to you, how about put a try for index and see the result.